# How to convert a floating point number into a string with precision? Arduino C++

Tags: c++, arduino, floating-point, precision, arduino-c++

I have a number like `3.14159` and I want it to be `3.1`

Arduino is being fussy with libraries for some reason. At the moment I can't use the `string` library.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up finding an awesome solution to this. Turns out Arduino has a method for this! It's just the `String()` method. So in order to convert `3.14159` simply type ⤵︎

```cpp
float num = 3.14159
String str1 = String(num, 1) // 3.1
String str2 = String(num, 2) // 3.14
String str3 = String(num, 3) // 3.141
```

So on the right of the comma is the decimal places parameter. It has a lot of functionality but that's one of the overloads. You can see them [all here!](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/)

Comment: To anyone reading: I wouldn't recommend this approach, unless it's some very basic sketch. The reason is that `String` is not equivalent to `std::string` and would fragment memory in the long run.

A `String` is an object supported by the String library. Using them is likely to fragment memory usage which with the limited resources available on the Arduino can cause problems.

A `std::string` is an array of chars terminated by a null. Using them does not fragment memory because they are not continually created and destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

As by default `sprintf` does not support floats in a standard Arduino environment, there's dtostrf() coming with avr-gcc, which does what you want. [Sample usage here](https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-float-vars)